# Can i have multiple Redux states (or a diferent structure) in my App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Basiclaly, i have an app with multiple reducers combined with combineReducers(), as a normal react-redux structure, looks something like this:

- App

  - State

    - Reducer 1
    - Reducer 2
    - Reducer 3

So, is there any way to have an structure like:

- App

  - State 1

    - Reducer 1
    - Reducer 2
  - State 2

    - Reducer 1
    - Reducer 2

Or in other hand, something like:

- App

  - State

    - General Reducer 1

      - Reducer 1
      - Reducer 2
      - Reducer 3
    - General Reducer 2

      - Reducer 1
      - Reducer 2
      - Reducer 3

I know this probably breaks Redux's structural rules and isn't going to be the prettiest piece of code you've ever seen, but I just want to test different factors.

Thanks for all beforehand!

Comment: Have a search for keywords: "redux slice". If I'm understanding correctly, that might be what you're after (It's not quite the same, but solves the same problem)

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    part1: combineReducers({
      sub1: subReducer1,
      sub2: subReducer2,
    }),
    part2: combineReducers({
      sub3: subReducer3,
      sub4: subReducer4,
    }),
  },
});
```

There is no "breaking rules" anything going on there. You own the state structure.